# Less CSS URL variable always shows server base URL before variable output

Tags: less

Consider this LESS code:

```
#login-form-submit {
    @base-url: "/webshop/rsc/img";
    background-image: url("@{base-url}/icons/login.png");
}
```

The output CSS is:

```
#login-form-submit {
    background-image: url("http://localhost:8080/webshop/rsc/css/specific//webshop/rsc/img/icons/login.png"); 
}
```

Does anybody know why this might be happening?  If I abandon the variable and use the string directly, the CSS outputs as expected. (Without the fully qualified URL.)

The server this is running on is jBoss EAP 5.

Comment: What happens if you make it a relative path? background-image: url("../../@{base-url}/icons/login.png"); or something like that.

Comment: are you using less.js server-side or are you compiling with something like less.app or codekit? If less.js, what version are you running? I ran your less above through the less.app compiler and it came out sans the local host URL. Not sure, but it may have to do with your server environment.

Comment: Apologies for the late response, I didn't realise a comment had been made... Matt, relative paths work fine, but aren't a scalable solution on this project.  Jonathan, I am using the client-side script (1.1.3) in this example, although this will be compiled server-side in production.  I think it is a server configuration too.  Perhaps I need to ask some jBoss experts, with a broader example.  Thank you both for responding.

Comment: As mentioned below this has been fixed, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640080/less-incorrectly-importing-files-with-urls/16756664#16756664

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is a problem where LESS is applying the relative URL to the beginning if the string starts with an interpolated variable. You could something like:

```
#login-form-submit {
  @url: "webshop/rsc/img";
  background-image: url("/@{url}/webshop/rsc/img");
}
```

For more info, [see this issue](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/409).

Comment: This doesn't work, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294126/anyway-to-set-a-common-image-path-for-less-files/11573279#11573279

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be fixed with LESS 1.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Until this bug in LESS is fixed (as @rcl mentions), a workaround is to always assume an absolute path for media that may be served from another location (say local server in dev, CDN in production).

```
background-image: url("http://@{base-url}/icons/login.png");
```

where

```
@base-url: "localhost/static";  /* in dev */
@base-url: "sample.cdn.com";  /* in production */
```

Comment: CSS shouldn't need to know about domains :(

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that you can work around this issue by compiling the less (in JavaScript) rather then relying on the browser "stylesheet/less" parsing. Invoking the parser via JavaScript seems to somehow avoid the issue completely.