# LESS incorrectly importing files with URLs

Tags: css, url, import, less

It seems that LESS' import strategy for URL doesn't account for relative paths the same as CSS does.

`test.less`

```
@import "sub/test.less";
div.a {
    background-image:url('imagea.jpg');
}
```

`sub/test.less`

```
div.b {
    background-image:url('imageb.jpg');
}
```

`output.css`

```
div.b {
    background-image:url('imageb.jpg');
}
div.a {
    background-image:url('imagea.jpg');
}
```

`correct_output.css`

```
div.b {
    background-image:url('sub/imageb.jpg');
}
div.a {
    background-image:url('imagea.jpg');
}
```

Is there a way to get this behavior from LessJS or is this a bug in the implementation?

Comment: Certainly looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/132).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been [fixed here](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/pull/331) it seems. As detailed **very** briefly under [usage](http://lesscss.org/#usage), here's how to apply the fix:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    less = {
        relativeUrls: true
    };
</script>
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It's quite concerning that LESS didn't do this already. You'd think that having backwards compatibility from CSS to LESS (valid CSS should be valid LESS) would be crucial.

Comment: I strongly agree, relativeUrls does indeed make sense.  
But be careful that writing `@import url("sub/test.less")` and compiling with `relativeUrls: true` would cause urls' path to be rewritten twice.  
So I recommend compiling with `relativeUrl` turned on but be sure to avoid `url(..)` inside your less `@import` statements if you don't want to go crazy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: ensure matching directory hierarchy.

```
~/root/lib/css/output.css
~/root/lib/less/test.less
~/root/images/imagea.jpg
~/root/images/imageb.jpg
```

Have the less file output to the css directory. In addition to having good directory structure, the relative path in the css file will match up and work correctly.

Comment: So the solution is just to "deal with it"™?

Comment: More or less. I'm glad that you brought this topic up though, because I've always been using the mentioned directory structure and, consequently, never ran into this bug before. It's useful to know where the boundaries lie and how to circumvent them.

Comment: This is horrible... surely it cannot be!