# Can less.js handle relative paths for images?

Tags: css, less

When using less.js, can you not use relative paths for images?  Like background:url(../img/header.jpg)

It seems to convert it to an absolute path, that is wrong.

Comment: make sure you've applied this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640080/less-incorrectly-importing-files-with-urls/16756664#16756664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try quoting the URL, I always do it this way to keep it neat though,

```
@header-image: "../img/header.jpg";

background: url(@header-image);
```

Also, the URL code can be seen on [github](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/tree/url.js). Looks like it is added if you are running in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, however I ran into a similar problem and the accepted answer did not work for me..  this did.

Set an @img-path variable to your desired relative path, then use that variable to force LESS to render using that path instead of an absolute path.

> @img-path: "/assets/images";
>
> background-image: url("@{img-path}/your-image.jpg");

Check out this other answer I found that pointed me down the right path:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296706/1896352