# glyphicon icons not appearing in my MVC site having bootstrap implemented

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, glyphicons

Following is my HTML markup

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i>
</button>
```

I have change following line variable.less

```
@icon-font-path:          "..\fonts";
```

the fonts folder contains four files - eot, svg, ttf and woff extension files for glyphicons-halflins

Following is how the folder structure is -

- Content\bootstrap.css
- Content\bootswatch.css
- Content\variables.less
- Contact\fonts-- all four files (extensions - eot, svg, ttf, and
  woff)

Any idea why it doesn't display icon in the webpage?

Any help on this much appreciated.

Comment: 1) Is this in development or once deployed? 2) Is what you've posted for `@icon-font-path` what it currently is, or what it was before you changed it? Your wording is unclear.

Comment: 1) this is in the development itself.. 2) @icon-font-path was same when I downloaded variables.less file from bootply...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a backslash for specifying the path. Have you tried it with a forward slash?
Have a look at [Is there a way to set a common image path for LESS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294126/anyway-to-set-a-common-image-path-for-less-files). All of them used forward slashes.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought that was the problem. But take a look at Chris Pratt's answer. I think he actually got it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your path is wrong, then. `variables.less` is in `/Content` and your font files are in `/Content/fonts`, but your path is saying go up one level from `/Content`, making it just `/` and then look for the `fonts` directory there, i.e. `/fonts`, not `/Content/fonts`. Remove the `../` portion of your font path and try again.