# less mixin, cannot get backgroung-image's url

Tags: less, mixins

here i want to create a less mixin. The parameter is brand and is should be changed into brand@2x.png. The code below did not work.

```
.bglogo (@brand) {
  @brandurl: @brand + '@2x.png';
  background-image: url(@brandurl);
}

.span{
  .bglogo('brand');
}
```

error message --

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there a way to set a common image path for LESS files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294126/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-common-image-path-for-less-files)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [variable interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation) in order to concatenate the variable and the string.

In your case, you would use the value `"@{brand}@2x.png"`:

```
.bglogo (@brand) {
  @brandurl: "@{brand}@2x.png";
  background-image: url(@brandurl);
}

.span {
  .bglogo('brand');
}
```

Result:

```
.span {
  background-image: url("brand@2x.png");
}
```

Comment: It works. Here I mistake it with stylus...Thank you!